# expanding the priorities table in runqueue in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I have a hw assignment that I'm having really hard time with, probably since I'm new to the whole Linux kernel thing.

we're supposed to add a new scheduling policy to the existing scheduling algorithm. those new policy processes have different priorities and they supposed to run after RT processes but before regular processes.

we've tried expanding the prio_array table size to fit in the new policy processes and we "shifted" all regular processes 140 down (new policy have 140 priorities). 
now, we've saved the normal process prio and used the "shift" only when inserting a process in to a runqueue.

the thing is now the linux kernel is not loading, it's just keeps rebooting. we've tried everything we could think of, but nothing works.

is our idea even posible? what could we have changed there to cause the problem?

is there a better way to implement what we need to do?